# How to parse certificate Subject string?

Tags: delphi, cryptoapi

Using `CertNameToStr` function you can get a certificate's Subject string:

> C=US, S=California, L=San Jose, O="Adobe Systems, Incorporated", OU=Digital ID Class 3 - Microsoft Software Validation v2, OU=Acrobat Engineering, CN="Adobe Systems, Incorporated"

My question is, how to parse it to get an array of name-value pairs?

I tried to use the `SplitString()` function with `,` character as a delimiter:

```
  StrArr := SplitString(edtSubjectStr.Text, ',');
  for I := Low(StrArr) to High(StrArr) do
    Memo1.Lines.Append(Trim(StrArr[i]));
```

but the result is unsatisfactory:

> C=US
>   S=California
>   L=San Jose
>   O="Adobe Systems
>   Incorporated"
>   OU=Digital ID Class 3 - Microsoft Software Validation v2
>   OU=Acrobat Engineering
>   CN="Adobe Systems
>   Incorporated"

Is there any API function to parse this subject string?

Or maybe there is a way of parsing it with some other Delphi components|classes|functions?

Comment: `SplitString()` doesn't take quoted strings into account.  Have you tried `TStringList` with its `CommaText` property?  Otherwise, you will just have to write your own parser, or find a 3rd party parser. This is a fairly simple text format to parse manually

Comment: As far as I know `TStringList.CommaText` consideres both spaces and commas as the delimiters.
I've been thinking about writing a parser manually, but decided to ask if there is any standard way

Comment: @ZurabD use the [`TStringsList.StrictDelimiter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings.StrictDelimiter) property to avoid `CommaText` delimiting on spaces

Comment: Just curios, how are you using the crypto api? Do you use certain open source library or is it a third party set?

Comment: @NasreddineGalfout I use `JEDI API Library & Security Code Library` just to have API declarations
https://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/ 
Look at `JwaWinCrypt.pas` module in the lib.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was looking for something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer:

just use `CERT_X500_NAME_STR or CERT_NAME_STR_CRLF_FLAG` as the value of the `dwStrType` property of the `CertNameToStr()` function and you'll get a `CRLF` separated string!